# How do I update my jailbroken Apple TV to 5.3?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv

I have a jailbroken Apple TV (black), which has firecore's aTV flash black installed.

How do I get it to update to the latest ios so I can use HBOGo?

Settings > General > Update just says "You are up to date", yet it's on version 5.0.2.

aTV flash updated to 2.3 without issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing over the air(thru apple tv) update, you may have installed a hack that disables automatic updates so you won't lose the jailbreak. 
Connect to your computer and do a DFU update or uninstall the hack that disables the update from within apple tv/nito or where ever it's installed and try updating again. Although I recommend DFU upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Try the manual update listed here: http://www.appletv3jailbreak.com/2013/07/firecore-updates-atv-flash-black-for.html

Comment: All I see there is "Go to settings > update", which, as I said, does not work on my box.

Comment: Immediately after that auto-update line is this part of the article: Or you can download the update files separately and manually install them. This means you will have to connect your Apple TV to your computer and use iTunes to deliver the newest software version.

Comment: Here are the manual install instructions, directly from Firecore: http://support.firecore.com/entries/346673-Installing-aTV-Flash-black-.  Does that help?